# Hausdorff but not regular spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{T}$ be the collection of subsets of $X$ in the form of $U\cup(V\cap \mathbb{Q})$, where $U,V$ are open in the usual sense(I am assuming this means $U, V$ are open intervals.) Show this is a topological space that is $T_2$ but not $T_3$.

My approach, take $x,y$ distinct in $X$, it is clear to me that this is Hausdorff, since we are on the real line, there exist disjoint open intervals $U_x,U_y$ that contain $x,y$. To show that it is not $T_3$. Assume to the contrary that it is $T_3$. Let $F$ be any closed set and $x\in F^\complement$, then there exists $O_1,O_2\in \mathcal{T}$ disjoint, such that $F\subset O_1, x\in O_2 $. We have $F\subset U\cup(V\cap \mathbb{Q})$ and $x\in U^\prime\cup(V^\prime\cap \mathbb{Q})$, I want to reach to some sort of contradiction here but I can't see any. Am I heading in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you consider the open set $\mathbb{Q}$ and show that no $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ has a closed neighbourhood contained in $\mathbb{Q}$? Have you written down what the closed sets in $X$ look like?